# encrypting a file with an RSA key

Tags: java, rsa, initialisation-vector

I wrote a java program to encrypt and decrypt files using AES algorithm in CBC mode and a random initialization vector. but there is something fundamental I'm not understanding:first I generate a random iv and load it to the cipher in the encrypt method.
then when I want to decrypt the file,do i need to load the **same** iv to the decrypt method?

Comment: If you want to encrypt files using RSA and AES, I strongly recommend you use GPG.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need the same IV to initialize the decryption process. The purpose of the IV in CBC mode is to ensure that encrypting the same plaintext will result in a different ciphertext each time. By the way, are you encrypting it using AES or RSA?